# Map several @QueryParam to one custom entity

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

For example, I have class

```
class MyQuery {
   Date start;
   Date end;
   ChronoUnit scale; // ChronoUnit is enum
}
```

I want to declare method like:

```
@Path("/myreport")
public Response generateReport(@EntityFromQuery MyQuery query) {
   // logic to generate.
}
```

and I want that this method will be invoked when something is hitting url

/myreport?start=2015-01-01&end=2015-01-31&scale=WEEKS

I'm using Jersey. Is there any internal tool to achieve this?
Or I need to write my own MessageBodyReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the `@BeanParam` annotation that you would use instead of `@EntityFromQuery` in the Java method of your JAX-RS Resouce.

In your `MyQuery` class, you just need to annotate the getters with `@QueryParam("start")`, etc.

See https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

That comes out of the box with jersey (you might want to check some tutorials first..). It might be easier for you to accept all GET-Parameters of your incoming requests as Strings and convert them later on:

```
@GET
@Path("/myreport")
@Produces(MediaType.{whatever you want to return})
public Response generateReport(@QueryParam("start") String start, @QueryParam ("end") String end, @QueryParam ("scale") String scale) {
   // convert from string to date and from string to chroneUnit
   //do some logic..
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I need to map to one entity, .
Btw, you can use enums in param without additionaly converting (and any class with public constructor with one string argument or static valueOf(String) method. 

The reason of these:
I have several different queries and this quries will be changed in future. I don't wan't to change converting every time I add new param to query.